# Как переместить курсор в текстовом редакторе?

Tags: delphi, winapi

Задача: открыть текстовый файл и переместить курсор в определенную позицию. Не могу разобраться с перемещения курсора в текстовом файле.

Привожу пример кода, как реализую перемещение курсора:

```
hd := ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'C:\Windows\Notepad.exe', PChar(fileName), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
SetFilePointer(hd, 50, nil, FILE_BEGIN);
```

где: `fileName` - полный путь до файла; `hd` типа HWND

Путь до файла получаю через `OpenDialog.FileName`.

Помогите разобраться в перемещении курсора в текстовом файле. Думаю, что я неправильно передаю Handle в `SetFilePointer`, но не понимаю, как это решить

Comment: Детали про поиск к вопросу не относятся - убрал )

Comment: Функция [SetFilePointer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer) перемещает указатель в _файле_. Она не имеет никакого отношения к текстовому курсору.

Comment: Смотрите функцию [SetCaretPos](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcaretpos). И в целом [Using Carets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-carets)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо за подсказку. Буду пробовать

Comment: @Kromster ок, учту)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov после открытия файла через ShellExecute пишу: `CreateCaret(hd, 0, 0, 0); SetCaretPos(500, 500); ShowCaret(hd);` и все равно каретка не перемещается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Сначала надо получить идентификатор окна редактирования текста. Это можно сделать, например, при помощи функций FindWindowEx;
2. Потом необходимо этому идентификатору отправить команду установить курсор в нужное место.

   ```
   var 
   Hndl: TWND;
   begin
     Hndl := FindWindow(0, 0, 'Notepad'{*}, nil); 
     Hndl := FindWindow(Hndl, 0, 'Edit', nil);
     if Hndl = 0 then
       ShowMessage('Не удалось найти открытый блокнот или получить хэндл редактора!')   
     else begin
       SendMessage(Hndl, EM_SETSEL, XXX{**}, XXX);    
     end; 
   end;
   ```

*) 'Notepad' - имя класса окна, а не название приложения, узнать его можно изучив приложение при помощи утилит вроде Window Detective.

**) XXX - это позиция, куда нужно установить курсор. Позиция считается в символах от начала текста, т.е. нельзя указать отдельно строку и столбец.

Comment: Большое спасибо, курсор перемещается) Только нужно подправить: вместо `FindWindow` написать `FindWindowEx` в обоих строках

Comment: Дополню еще. В моём случае я запускаю блокнот через `ShellExecute`, а затем сразу ищу _Handle_ окна, т.е.

`ShellExecute(...);`

`Hndl := FindWindowEx(0, 0, 'Notepad', nil);`

В этом случае _Handle_ не будет найдет (видимо потому, что на момент выполнения кода блокнот еще не успел запуститься и соответственно _Handle_ не найден). Чтобы это решить добавил между этими строками `sleep(100)` - не совсем удачное решение. Если есть какие идеи, буду благодарен?

Comment: sleep() не очень правильно, лучше использовать что-то вроде [WaitForInputIdle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-waitforinputidle).Ну или тот же Sleep, но в цикле, т.е. подождали 100-200 мс, поискали блокнот, не нашли - повторить. Если за несколько секунд не дождались - сообщить об ошибке.